# Unable to display associated model's fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hey all, 
    I'm having a pretty weird problem and am having trouble isolating the cause. I get the feeling its a simple solution, but I was hoping for a nudge in the right direction. I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pnotes  

class Pnote < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :preport
belongs_to :user  

class Preport < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pnotes, :dependent=>:destroy
```

The Pnote portion of my schema looks as so:

```
create_table "pnotes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "preport_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I'm trying to display all of the Pnotes associate with a given Preport on the show page of the Preport

My Preport Controller has the following code for the show action:

```
def show
    @board = Board.find(params[:board_id])
    @preport = @board.preport
    @pnotes = @preport.pnotes
    @pnote=@preport.pnotes.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @preport }
    end
  end
```

So now in my show.html.erb in the Preports folder, I am trying to display a list of the Pnotes as such:

```
<ul>
<% @pnotes.each do |pnote| %>
 <li><%= pnote.user.login %><span>-<%=pnote.content %></span></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

"login" is the standard field that came along with the Devise Authentication Gem.

However, this gives me the following error:

> undefined method `login' for nil:NilClass

If I change the view to this:

<%= pnote.user%>-<%=pnote.content %>

I get :

```
#<User:0x106c25888>-Testing
```

, so it appears that it is identifying the associated user, but unable to grab its attributes.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I feel like there is a fairly small oversight going on here, but I am unable to distinguish from exactly where

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using a very old version of Devise that I'm not aware of, the User model wouldn't have a `login` attribute.

Try `email` instead.

Comment: The user model does have an email column, but the client actually requested to have a different login field as well.   It (using .login that is) works in other parts of the application without issue, so I'm not sure if that's the cause  

The user model also has a full_name field that I am able to rely upon in other parts of the application...but it is giving me the same problems here as I am getting with 'login'